# How to do matrix division if the denominator matrix is non-invertible?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I tried to create a script for Markov reliability modelling according to [this page.](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath232/part3/part3.htm) I have a tough time to understand this particular line from the website:

> The average probabilities for the interval beginning at time nT is given by 
>   $$\overline{P(t)_n} = \frac{1}{T} \int _{t=0}^T (A e^{\textbf{M}T})^n P(0)  \, {\rm d} t = \frac{e^{\textbf{M}T} - \textbf{I}}{\textbf{M}T} (A e^{\textbf{M}T})^n P(0)$$
>   where **I** is the identity matrix. Notice that the numerator on the right hand side is divisible by **M**T, so it isn’t necessary to invert the **M** matrix.

I tried to find the inverse, but the matrix is non-invertible. My question is, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: They say it in the quoted text. $e^{MT}-I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(MT)^n$, which is divisible by $MT$. You get that $\frac{e^{MT}-I}{MT}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(MT)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I think the equation is quite heavy computationally. Is there another way to model it?

Comment: In your case $M$ [seems to be diagonalizable](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B-%28a%2Bb%29%2Cb%2Bc%2Ca%5D%2C%5Ba%2C-%28b%2Bc%29%2C0%5D%2C%5Bb%2C0%2C-a%5D%5D). This means that there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}DP=M$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then $\frac{e^{MT}-I}{MT}=P^{-1}\frac{e^{DT}-I}{Dt}P$, but in the case of a diagonal matrix $DT$ the matrix $\frac{e^{DT}-I}{Dt}$ is the diagonal matrix that consists of applying the function $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ to each entry in the diagonal of $DT$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I tried both of your suggestions and the results for both cases are diverge. The former case which I was able to model successfully was using [Jordan form](https://www.math24.net/method-matrix-exponential/), but I see the problem is quite different.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the $T$ is used as the maximum or upper limit of the integral as far as I know. I apologize because the format was  different from what I saw in the original post, I have corrected it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the $T$ is a scalar constant, while $t$ is a variable which is used for the integration.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I just took the equation from [this website](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath232/part3/part3.htm). Also, the $\textbf{M}T$ is non-invertible.

Comment: Can you explain how you tried using MoonLightSyzygy's suggestion of diagonalization? It should work. For diagonal entries which are zero, substitute $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\exp x-1}x=1$ instead.

Comment: @Rahul I used eigen vector as $P$ and eigen value for $D$. However, one of the eigen value is zero, which led to zero in the exponential term. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Rahul I have tried to implement your suggestion, finally the result is converging. However, the magnitude is still not quite right though.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider only the case where the matrix of interest is diagonalizable. Suppose we have diagonalizable matrix $\rm A$, whose eigendecomposition is

$$\rm A = V \Lambda V^{-1} = V \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_1 & \rm{O}\\ \rm{O} & \rm{O}\end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$$

where diagonal matrix $\Lambda_1$ contains the non-zero eigenvalues of $\rm A$ on its main diagonal. After some work, it can be shown that

$$e^{t \rm{A}} = \rm V \begin{bmatrix} e^{t \Lambda_1} & \rm{O}\\ \rm{O} & \rm{I}\end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$$

Hence, integrating over interval $[t_i, t_f]$, we obtain

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f} e^{t \rm{A}} \,\rm{d}t = \rm V \begin{bmatrix} \displaystyle\int_{t_i}^{t_f} e^{t \Lambda_1} \,\rm{d}t& \rm{O}\\ \rm{O} & (t_f - t_i) \, \rm{I}\end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$$

and, since $\Lambda_1$ is invertible, the integral should be straightforward to compute.